# Change the case on Mc surnames to proper case

Tags: sql-server, uppercase, lowercase

I run a function to update some columns on a few tables to change UPPERCASE to ProperCase. I didn't take into account the 'Mc' or 'Mac' surnames. So now all my McSurnames have changed to Mcsurnames.

Does anyone have any scripts that would amend to McSurname?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: My name is Machado and I come from Portugal, what will you do to my name? Or do you only have Irish and Scottish origin names?

Comment: 95% of names are Irish, only a few that may vary, which we can deal with individually within the application that uses the DB

Comment: What have you considered and tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. just trying to see if there is a way that doesn't completely mess up the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a slippery slope.  You will find many exceptions.  That said, here is a scaled down version of my proper function.

**Example**

```
Select [dbo].[svf-Str-Proper]('john old macdonald ii phd,dds llc')
```

**Reurns**

```
(No column name)
John Old MacDonald II PhD,DDS LLC
```

**The Function if Desired**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[svf-Str-Proper] (@S varchar(max))
Returns varchar(max)
As
Begin
    Set @S = ' '+replace(replace(Lower(@S),'   ',' '),'  ',' ')+' '
    ;with cte1 as (Select * From (Values(' '),('-'),('/'),('\'),('['),('{'),('('),('.'),(','),('&'),(' Mc'),(' Mac'),(' O''') ) A(P))
         ,cte2 as (Select * From (Values('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K'),('L'),('M')
                                       ,('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V'),('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')
                                       ,('LLC'),('PhD'),('MD'),('DDS')
                                       ,('II '),('III '),('IV ')
                                       ,('ID '),('PW ')
                                 ) A(S))
         ,cte3 as (Select F = Lower(A.P+B.S),T = A.P+B.S From cte1 A Cross Join cte2 B 
                   Union All 
                   Select F = Lower(B.S+A.P),T = B.S+A.P From cte1 A Cross Join cte2 B where A.P in ('&') 
                  ) 
    Select @S = replace(@S,F,T) From cte3 
    Return rtrim(ltrim(@S))
End
```

Comment: Thanks John, worked a treat - do you have a link to your full proper case script?

Comment: @MalcolmPH Sorry, my proper function is actually linked to a table so that we can maintain exceptions

Answer (score 0):

If we start by putting the prefix in a variable.

Then we need to filter the table so that it has at least two characters after that.

We update the table, so that the new value is the prefix, followed by the uppercase of the next letter, followed by the rest of the original value.

```
DECLARE @prefix nvarchar(100) = 'Mc'; -- or Mac

UPDATE table
SET lastname = @prefix + UPPER(SUBSTRING(lastname, LEN(@prefix) + 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(lastname, LEN(@prefix) + 2, LEN(lastname)
WHERE lastname LIKE @prefix + '[a-z][a-z]%';
```

You can run this twice with the two different prefixes.

Comment: Would be a much better answer if you actually described what it does. You know that code-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: so prefix all Mcxxxxxx with Mc = McMcxxxxxxx then replace McMc with McX??

Comment: No, we skip the first few letters (the length of the prefix). It becomes `'Mc' + 'X' + 'xxxxxx'`