Lower some words from InitCap function
I have this function above in SQL Server 2016 to change first character to upper:
FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
    BEGIN
        IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
            SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
    END

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @OutputString

END

But now I need that some words in a list it's always lower:
de
da
do
dos
das
d'

How can I change the code to fix it ?

A good first step would be to assemble the words from the @InputString a character at a time so that you can compare them to a list of words to be left in lowercase.

try something like this if @inputString in ('de','da','do') return @inputString else...

Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66588546/change-the-case-on-mc-surnames-to-proper-case/66588802#66588802   You can append cte2 with the lowercase overrides.

Honestly, this is better done in the presentation layer, not the SQL. Many programming languages have a formatting options for "Proper Case".

I think going for HABO's advise might be most practical. I have modified the code and added the evaluation of each word to check against a list
FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 

RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Index INT
DECLARE @Char CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @CurrentWord VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @WordStartIndex INT

-- Table to hold words that should always be lowercase
DECLARE @LowercaseWords TABLE (Word VARCHAR(255))

-- Populate the table with words that must remain in lowercase
INSERT INTO @LowercaseWords (Word)
VALUES ('and'), ('the'), ('of'), ('in'), ('on'), ('or'), ('to'), ('for') -- Add your words that you want lower caps in here.

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1
SET @CurrentWord = ''
SET @WordStartIndex = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    -- Check if new word is starting
    IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
    BEGIN
        -- Reset current word
        SET @CurrentWord = ''
        SET @WordStartIndex = @Index
    END

    -- Append current character to current word
    SET @CurrentWord = @CurrentWord + @Char


    IF @Char IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(', ')') OR @Index = LEN(@InputString)
    BEGIN
        -- Check if the current word is in the table of lowercase words
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @LowercaseWords WHERE Word = LTRIM(RTRIM(@CurrentWord)))
        BEGIN
            SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @WordStartIndex, 1, UPPER(SUBSTRING(@CurrentWord, 1, 1)))
        END
    END

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @OutputString
END

